# Who is the second child in Ecclesiastes 4:15?

Tags: referent-identification, ecclesiastes

YLT - 4:13 Better is a poor and wise youth than an old and foolish king, who hath not known to be warned any more. YLT - 4:14 For from a house of prisoners he hath come out to reign, for even in his own kingdom he hath been poor. YLT - 4:15 I have seen all the living, who are walking under the sun, with the second youth who doth stand in his place; YLT - 4:16 there is no end to all the people, to all who were before them; also, the latter rejoice not in him. Surely this also is vanity and vexation of spirit.

It is not clear to me whether the second youth is the poor and wise one of Eccl 4:13 and what is it happening here, does he stands in the place of the old and fool king?

Answer (score 1):

The poor and wise youth is the second birth which must “out of prison come to reign” like Joesph -  or like the Bride coming out of the wilderness - like Israel coming out of the desert.  The first generation - the first birth - which will not be admonished - must die. (“The flesh lusts against the spirit and the spirit against the flesh, and these are contrary to one another, that you cannot do the things that you would.”)  The elder must serve the younger, the second birth must reign.  We must endure the trials and the wilderness with God until our old nature has been crucified, and it is no longer we who live, but Christ in us.  So let us not think it strange when the fiery trials come like some strange thing is happening to us, but let us rejoice, lifting up our head as we see the day approaching and our redemption drawing near.  That day when Jesus wins the fight in us, Satan has been crushed under our feet, and, like many who have come before us, we no longer live, but Christ lives his life through us.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your contribution.  Please take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.  This answer needs some references to support the argument and assertions.

Answer (score 0):

I considered all the living — The general disposition of common people in all kingdoms, that they are fickle and inconstant, weary of their old governors, and desirous of changes; with the second child that shall stand up — That shall arise to reign. This may be understood of the king’s child, or son and heir, called second in respect to his father, whose successor he is.

Most modern interpreters regard the “second child” as identical with the “young man” of Ecclesiastes 4:13, and understand the passage, “I saw him at the head of all his people; yet his great popularity was but temporary, and the next generation took no pleasure in him.” It seems to me that by no stretch of rhetoric can “all the living which walk under the sun” be taken for the subjects of the sovereign in question. I am inclined to think that the Preacher reverts to the general topic, and considered all the living with the “second youth,” i.e., the second generation which shall succeed them. He saw the old generation hardened in its ways, and incapable of being admonished, and then displaced by a new generation, with which the next will feel equal dissatisfaction.

Sources:

https://biblehub.com/commentaries/ecclesiastes/4-15.htm

Comment: Thank you indeed. I was thinking of the second child as the second one that is lacking as a son or a brother in Eccl 4:8. May be a reference to the Mashiach, typified by Joseph who reigned as a second of the kingdom of Egypt (this hint comes from Rashi) and came out of the house of the prisoners. But also David was bor as a poor sheperd... Could the old king be a representation of Saul? Mashiach's kingdom has numberless subjects, and nowadays many would not be happy to have him ruling over their lives...

Comment: I should've put in quotes and sited sources sorry, my answer is a combination of commentaries from https://biblehub.com/commentaries/ecclesiastes/4-15.htm

Answer (score 0):

> **Ecclesiastes 4:15 (DRB)** I saw all men living, that walk under the sun with the second young man, who shall rise up in his place.

This seems to refer to the apparent vanity of life: when one life is ending, there pops up (signified by "youth" or "young boy" -  *ha yeled*) another no less entitled to life than he, in a seemingly endless cycle; no one is 'special,' and "nothing is new under the sun" (1:9). The point of the chapter - and the book - is driving home the vanity of life without a governing structure or purpose - a *telos*.

(The word *sheni* (second) may allow for the translation, "yet another" instead of "second," however, this might only be possible if we ignore the define articles, depending on how wide one makes the context.)

Answer (score 0):

The ordinal article haš·šê·nî is most commonly translated as ‘the second’, although the ESV translation is ‘that youth’. The use of this ordinal article denotes a change in subject from the king (the original subject) to the youth (a secondary subject), before reverting back to the king.

> Better was a poor and wise youth than an old and foolish king who no longer knew how to take advice. 14 For he went from prison to the throne, though in his own kingdom he had been born poor. 15 I saw all the living who move about under the sun, along with that[b] youth who was to stand in the king's[c] place. 16 There was no end of all the people, all of whom he led. Yet those who come later will not rejoice in him. Surely this also is vanity and a striving after wind.

In this translation, the relevant notation is: [b] *the second*; [c] *his*, which offers a more direct translation, but one which is less clear in English.

The author appears to be referring to the potential of the poor and wise youth, compared to that of an old and foolish king who no longer heeds advice and thus has nothing to look forward to except his inevitable death. After his death, the people he led (including this youth he considers *better* than the king) will continue, and later generations won’t value this old and foolish king in the way he currently enjoys.

The ‘vanity and striving after the wind’ in this case refers to the pointlessness of having ‘arrived’ at the summit of power and influence in a temporary life.

Answer (score 0):

The key to grasping Eccl 4:15 is the rest of the sentence as rendered by numerous versions:

- NIV: followed the youth, the king's successor.
- NLT: another youth who replaces him.
- ESV: that youth who was to stand in the king’s place.
- BSB: followed this second one, the youth who succeeded the king.
- BASB: second lad who replaces him.
- CEV: follow a young leader who came to power after the king was gone.
- GNT: a young man who will take the king's place.
- NET: the youth who will take the king's place.

Thus, the (second) youth is the heir to the old king's throne who replaces the king on his death.  Thus, the youth is send in line to the throne that become king when the king passes.

The Hebrew שֵׁנִי translated "second" by the KJV is the adjective whose BDB meaning is list below.  Here it simply means "second" in the sense of the one who come after the primary (king in this case).

=====================================

APPENDIX - BDB meaning of שֵׁנִי masculine שֵׁנִית feminine157

> adjective ordinal number second; — בַּיּוֺם הַשֵּׁנִי Exodus 2:13 +,
> etc. (שֵׁנִי82t. + Nehemiah 3:30, read שֵׁנִית; read וְהַשֵּׁנִי also
> 1 Chronicles 6:13 for ושני); בַּשָּׁנָה הַשֵּׁנִית Genesis 47:18 +,
> etc. (שֵׁנִית72t. + Nehemiah 3:30 see above), ׳שִׁבְעַת יָמִים שׁ
> Leviticus 13:5; Leviticus 13:93; Leviticus 13:54 a second heptad of
> days; שֵׁנִית = a second time Genesis 22:15 16t. + (= again, of
> similar — not identical — act, or another point in a series) Ezekiel
> 4:6; Malachi 2:13, וְהַשֵּׁנִית 2 Samuel 16:19; masculine plural
> שְׁנִיִּם Numbers 2:16 they shall set out as second, but Genesis 6:16
> second stories (in ark).